# Best approach to telling if there are more results than requested (paging)?

Tags: c#, sql, pagination

I'm running a query that retrieves 20 rows (for example). I want to know if there are 21 so I can enable the 'next page' button accordingly. At the moment I'm retrieving pageSize + 1 and returning a boolean as an out parameter which is assigned it's value based on whether there were 21 (in this case) rows retrieved but will only actually return the 20 as a List. This means I'm retrieving an extra one though which I then just disregard which isn't ideal for performance and I don't want to run a count(*) because it's another query altogether.

NOTE: Using a pageddatasource isn't really an option, got to stick with rowlimit's and start rows.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested query, something like this:

```
 select    TOP 20 *,
           (select count(*) from tableName) as TotalCount
 from      tableName
```

Then each row will have the total column, so you can check that.

Alternatively, you could use this syntax, avoiding the nested select. This will become more convenient when you have additional predicates (which don't have to be repeated in the nested select):

```
 select    TOP 20 *, count(*) over() as TotalCount
 from      tableName
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was after. Thanks a lot mate, don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

2 queries:

1. the page of results
2. then total number of results

the first query will contain the page and page size, the second will provide you with the total number of rows. With this information you can calculate the total number of pages and present this to the user.

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate your reply - but like I say I want to avoid using another query to count results. Is this the only way around it? +1.

Comment: this is the common approach. and 1 additional scalar query will not be problem. besides 2 queries != 2 sqlcommands. you can define 2 queries within the sql command and move through the result sets. or if you are using an ORM like NH you can use futures to issue multiple queries with 1 remote call.

Answer (score 1):

I would doubt that retrieving one extra row (21 vs 20) within the same DB access is anything but negligible in terms of performance.

Comment: The query is complex, and as negligible as it seems - it does no harm to look for better alternatives. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the count(*) for one time. Use it to display the number of pages.
2. Each time user clicks page number, get the 20 records

Comment: This also makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot. I think it's important for me to keep this paging as upto date as possible as the amount of pages I'm searching for is quite dynamic. +1 anyway.

Comment: then you seems to have better approrach pageSize+1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select *,Row_Number .... as RowNo
into #Table
from Table

Select * 
from #Table
WHERE RowNo > @FirstRec AND RowNo < @LastRec

Select count(*)
from #Table
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that it's not a stored procedure sorry, just one SQL command.

Comment: In this case your are only executing one query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that uses row_number

```
–-Change these two variable to parameters of your
–-actual stored procedure

Declare @PageNumber int
Declare @PageSize int


–-Assume we need page 6 i.e. records from 51-60
Select @PageNumber=6
Select @PageSize=10


–-Select only those records which
–-fit into a single page
Select Top(@PageSize) * from
(
Select
RowID=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name),
ProductID,Name,ProductNumber,ListPrice,
TotalRows=Count(*) OVER() --Count all records
from Production.Product
) A
Where A.RowId > ((@PageNumber-1)*@PageSize)
```